# Style only applied when not providing DTD

Tags: html, css, styles, doctype

I'm trying to use a valid doctype, but if I use the one below, with the URL, the links refuse to maintain the `#ffffff` text color assigned at the 200 width table (and) the background color wipes all through the two rows (both the google and yahoo links).  Comment out the Doctype URL, and it works fine... can anyone shed some insight on this>

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01     Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>test.com</title>
<style type="text/css">
td.off{background: #223C66}
td.on{background: #2d2dff}
</style>
<style>
a{text-decoration:none}
a:hover{text-decoration:underline}
</style>
</head>

<table width="600" align="center" style="border:10px solid black; border-collapse:collapse;" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">

<tr>
<td>

<table width="200" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="10" border="0">
<tr>
<td height="40" class="off" onmouseover="this.className='on'" onmouseout="this.className='off'">
<a href="http:\\www.google.com"><font color=#ffffff size=2 face=arial>valid google link</font></a>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td height="40" class="off" onmouseover="this.className='on'" onmouseout="this.className='off'">
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com" target="_blank"><font color=#ffffff size=2 face=arial>valid yahoo link</font></a>
</td>
</tr>

</table>

</td>

<td style="border:1px solid black; border-collapse:collapse;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<a href="http:\\www.msn.com">valid msn.com link</a>
<p>plain test - no link</p>
</td>
</tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unrelated sidenote, are you restricted to HTML 4.01? There's HTML5 now with easier doctype declaration `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Comment: What actually happens and on which browser(s)? The description is obscure and does not match the behavior in the browsers I tested. In comments, you are referring to underlines. Please edit the *question* to describe the problem. Please specify whether you are referring to initial behavior or to something that happens on mouseover. If the former, why does the demo contain CSS and JavaScript for mouseover effects?

Comment: @Jukka, thanks for the help. I am only testing in IE8. Without the dtd url code (following //EN"), using just the first part of the doctype, (including the ending >), when hovering, the left side td links (google & yahoo) display with a white underline, and the cell background color switches color. Also, the background table color can be seen between the (2) table data cells (the google and yahoo link cells).  The msn link displays a normal blue underline when hovering, that's ok. When adding the rest of the doctype url, the white underlines end up blue, and the td cell colors wash over.

Comment: @Jukka, I don't know which part is java, I thought I just had css. I have been piecing together this code, and haven't learned enough yet. This is a problem with the doctype, with and without the second part (the url). The only difference I can find is the absence of the url. It's interesting, because if anything, it should switch to quirks without the url, not the otherway around.  PS, I have modified to remove all errors per w3 validator, and it still doesn't work. I am puzzled... thanks for anything you can suggest... kevans

Comment: You still haven’t edited the question to describe the actual problem as per your comments. Moreover, the code is a total mess and is best rewritten rather than fixed.

Comment: @Jukka...seriously... ! i've described the issue more than once... thanks anyway...

Answer (score 4):

You need to make sure all attribute values are wrapped in `"` quotation marks in order to be valid.

Eg:

```
<font color="#ffffff" size="2" face="arial">
```

Also, it is good practice to use a validation tool on your markup: [W3C Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/check) http://validator.w3.org/check

**Added:** Full version with proper markup, should validate as HTML 4.01 Transitional

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test.com</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            td.off {
                background: #223C66;
            }
            td.on {
                background: #2d2dff;
            }
            a {
                text-decoration:none;
            }
            a:hover {
                text-decoration:underline;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table width="600" align="center" style="border:10px solid black; border-collapse:collapse;">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table width="200" border="0">
                        <tr>
                             <td height="40" class="off" onmouseover="this.className='on'" onmouseout="this.className='off'">
                                 <a href="http://www.google.com"><font color="#ffffff" size="2" face="arial">valid google link</font></a>
                             </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                             <td height="40" class="off" onmouseover="this.className='on'" onmouseout="this.className='off'">
                                 <a href="http://www.yahoo.com" target="_blank"><font color="#ffffff" size="2" face="arial">valid yahoo link</font></a>
                             </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
              </td>
              <td style="border:1px solid black; border-collapse:collapse;" >
                  <a href="http://www.msn.com">valid msn.com link</a>
                  <p>plain test - no link</p>
               </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Konrad, I just added quote marks, still doesn't work. Take the code, save, open and take a look. Then take out the doctype url... then it will look like what I'm trying to do...added comment... yes, I need to make this work with  4.01 transitional, as it's all mostly older html coding, very little css...

Comment: sorry sweetamylase, that was you that suggested quote marks... didn't catch that... I was hoping that was it...

Comment: @kevans I put it up test page based on your markup: http://jsfiddle.net/XBzKd/  Also, validator is saying `cellspacing` and `cellpadding` aren't valid HTML4.0 attributes. So maybe it's best you move all styling to your CSS instead of using element attributes.

Comment: @sweetamylase... I'm not "there" yet, try it without the dtd url, see what it does, but yes, I will be taking your advise, just not complete enough.  If I take out the entire doctype, it works.  Again, this is almost all without css, just straight "notepad" html.

Comment: sorry guys, it is the link underlines that won't keep the assigned (inherited) link ffffff color.  instead, they adopt the default IE8 color. take out the dtd url, then the underlines maintain color.

Comment: kevans edit: ran through validator, edited per errors and warnings, removed cellpadding & cellspacing, even though validator says "must use 4.01 transitional to get the target attributes" (which I am using - see the doctype), didn't work, then used the "tidy cleaner" to redo the page, made it worse.  I've tried multiple iterations, nothing works... the only thing that works is removing the url.  any thoughts...?

Comment: @kevans Are you referring to `<a href="http://www.msn.com">valid msn.com link</a>` or `<font color="#ffffff" size="2" face="arial">valid google link</font>`?

Comment: @sweetamylase...referring to the second one, the google and yahoo links. the msn link is different, takes on normal IE8 color underlines, but I was trying to have the other two inherit the text color.  Thanks again... kevans

Comment: @kevans So you want the google and yahoo links to be the normal color of links (naturally blue/purple)? http://jsfiddle.net/fd7nN/ The reason those two appeared white is because of `<font color="#ffffff">` being applied to them.

Comment: @sweeyamylase... no... when hovering, I want the google & yahoo links to turn on and be white.  the links thenselves (the text) start out white, and should stay white.  Without the doctype url, it works, with the url, the google and yahoo underlines are normal blue/purple.  That's the problem, I want to keep them white... thanks again...

Comment: @kevans I think I know why, with the doctype the browser doesn't like the process the colors applied by `<font color="#ffffff">`. I have altered and removed the `<font>` tags and used a classname `light` instead, and style them using CSS. See http://jsfiddle.net/C5uHc/

Comment: @sweetamylase...thanks a bunch...that's really, really, really close!! The only thing not there, is correct rendering of the background table cell color. What I have is two cells with darkblue, separated by color showing through from the table background.  When I hover, I want the cell color to switch, along with the white underlines turning on. But yes!!! the underlines work.  The only way I can see it on js, is to enter the "share full screen result" url into google address bar. How else can I see the code you modified, at least to see what you did?  That would be a big help. thanks!

Comment: @sweetamylase...followup... when hovering, the cell colors switch, which is correct, but the cells are touching, with no space showing through, what I was looking for are two distinct cells, with the background table color showing between them.  But, I can continue working on that, the main thing was the link underlines not maintaining the white text color, but I'll keep at it... thanks so much for the help...

Comment: @kevans Use CSS to create that spacing around elements using `padding` property. Eg. `td { padding: 10px; }` Here see this one, I added a ton of comments into the CSS and HTML to explain: http://jsfiddle.net/tVKCM/

Comment: @sweetamylase... hello again. I see the padding, but I'm also trying to have the two cells vertically separated by either padding or some other method to result in two distinct cells, without the upper cell (along the bottom edge) touching the lower cell (along its top edge). But, please... you have already provided a significant amount of help, and I don't want you to be troubled too much. Your comments and efforts have provided me with a huge amount of insight, and have given me a block of code that I can learn more from. I will experiment with it and see how far I can get. it's helped a lot

Comment: @kevans That's find, just keep experimenting, here is another way to get the result you want, added a new `class` name *box*: http://jsfiddle.net/amyamy86/rkGdA/

Comment: @sweetamylase... you did it !!...exactly what I was after. Now, I've got a new example that I can use to get my (first) pages working... You've been a big help... and I just want to say thanks for the time you spent on this... thanks again & cheers...